# How to use FlywayDB without align databases with Production dump?

Tags: java, database, synchronization, flyway

I'd like to start using a flyway to keep our different db environments synced.

The problem I have is that we can't align all the environments using a Prod dump on test and dev since our Prod env contains sensitive data that testers and developers can't access.

I understand that to start using flyway on an existing environment the steps are:

1. Create Prod dump
2. Execute Flyway Init
3. Align Test with prod dump
4. Execute Flyway Clean on Dev
5. Execute prod dump on Dev
6. Start using flyway migration normaly

I based on [Axel Fontaine's video](http://vimeo.com/74437803) on minute 32:00 maybe there is another way to achieve this. So the question is how can I do to use flyway without using a production dump? Any help or idea?

Comment: I believe you can dump just the schema, without data. Are you allowed to do so?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Does that allow me to avoid having unsensitive data without losing production data on every migration execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as I said in the talk, dump the structure and the reference data. These are the things you will be managing using Flyway. The application data doesn't need to be dumped.

What you want is the structure and the reference data to be in sync, not the application data.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks a lot for you comment. It's a pleasure to get your answer.